# Does WaitForMultipleObjects in Windbg indicate an issue with Events in a .NET application?

Tags: .net, windbg

Currently I'm taked with fixing an application hang in a .NET application.  Following some research I found that windbg could provide insights in to what is happening in the application at the time it hangs.

Following the application hanging on a users system I've used windbg to gather some more information.

Firstly, I identified the GUI/STA thread (looking for CorExeMain)

```
0:011> ~*
   0  Id: 1488.314 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
      Start: mscoree!_CorExeMain_Exported (79004ddb) 
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
```

I noticed the following:

```
0:000> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0012eb2c 7c90df2c ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0012eb30 7c809574 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0012ebcc 7e4195f9 KERNEL32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
0012ec28 7752ebd6 USER32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e
0012ec50 77557237 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x80
0012ecc4 79f9e14d ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcf
0012ece4 79f9e0b4 mscorwks!NT5WaitRoutine+0x51
0012ed50 79f9e018 mscorwks!MsgWaitHelper+0xa5
0012ed70 79f4c664 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x28
0012edf4 79f4c6f9 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c
0012ee44 79f15a68 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
```

My experience with windbg is limited, but from the research I've carried out I get the impression that WaitForMultipleObjects indicates that it could be waiting for an event.  Can anyone tell me if this is a likely cause?

There are a few warnings that I've received which make me wonder if I haven't set the environment up correctly:

```
0012ee44 79f15a68 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\6d667f19d687361886990f3ca0f49816\mscorlib.ni.dll
0012ef48 792b68af mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitOneNative+0x156
```

And

```
0012f2ac 03af4dea USER32!DispatchMessageW+0xf
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0012f2c8 7b1d8d2e 0x3af4dea
```

Can anyone suggest whether there are any grounds to the thought I had of the application waiting for an event, or if anyone has any immediate ideas of possible causes or areas that may be worth investigating?

I'm also wondering if it would be worth following up with Son of Strike?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the *native* callstack of a *managed* thread. That wait is part of the internals of .NET. It may come to the point that you are digging that deep to figure out what is going on, but what you are really concerned with is the *managed* state of the application.

You can do this by loading the sos extension into windbg. It bridges the gap between the native nature of windbg and .NET.

The command to load this extension is different between versions of the .NET framework but it will be something like:

```
.loadby sos clr
```

...or possibly...

```
.loadby sos mscorwks
```

From there, you can use the exports sos provides you to debug your .NET application. As a starting point, you will want the managed callstack. This should point you to where in your code the hang is occurring.

```
!clrstack
```

MSDN has a good reference on what the sos extension provides.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx